# パワーポイントのリンクされた背景画像をVBAで再現するには？

Tags: vba, powerpoint

パワーポイントでは、リンクされた画像を背景に設定できますが、これをVBAで再現する方法が調べても判りませんでした。
ご教示頂けますでしょうか？